# java.lang.StackOverflowError in Thread main

Tags: java, canvas, netbeans, graphics, awt

I am trying to draw a string in a Canvas. The error occurs when I instantiate the class that extends `Canvas`, why am I getting it?

**Error stack**

```
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
at canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:20)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:17)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:17)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:17)`
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Canvas extends JFrame{

DrawCanvas cc = new DrawCanvas();

public Canvas(){
    super("Canvas");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(100, 100);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(cc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
}

private class DrawCanvas extends Canvas{
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("String", 10, 10);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why are you hiding the question itself? how can we answer if you don't provide the stacktrace completely?

Comment: Write the code here

Comment: The stack trace continues repeating at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas$DrawCanvas.<init>(Canvas.java:35)
at canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:17)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're doing wrong: The `Canvas` constructor makes a new `DrawCanvas`, but the `DrawCanvas` extends `Canvas` and since you're not specifying a different constructor, it takes the constructor of its superclass (`Canvas`) and therefore also makes a new `DrawCanvas`, which makes another `DrawCanvas`... ad infinitum. Therefore your code:

```
new DrawCanvas()
```

results in infinite recursion.

**Did you mean to extend [`java.awt.Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) instead?**

Also, you might want to avoid giving your classes similar names to those found in the Java API, *especially* if you're using those similarly-named classes.

Comment: Thank you, what I've to change to execute the paint method?

Comment: @Filippo Well I'd change your class names first. You want to extend the Java `Canvas` do you not? Either you can write `extends java.awt.Canvas` or rename your `JFrame` to something else like `MyWIndow`. Because I think you don't intend to make the `Canvas` extend your `JFrame`.

Comment: Now it work, i was extending the my project's Canvas class instead java.awt.Canvas, Thank